# Algorithm to distribute variably-sized items into balanced groups preserving items order

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, logic

I'm seeking for a solution to split a list of items with varying sizes into N number of similarly-sized groups while preserve items order.

That it is a Johnson's algorithm or Bin Packing. Still I dont know how to implement it for N-groups and preserve items order.

Example of distributing into 3 groups:

Items to distribute:

- Item A - size 5
- Item B - size 1
- Item C - size 8
- Item D - size 2
- Item E - size 3

Desired output:

```
Group 1 (total size 6): Item A, Item B
Group 2 (total size 8): Item C
Group 3 (total size 5): Item D, Item E
```

```js
function distributeItems(items, numGroups) {
    const totalItems = items.length;
    const groupSizes = Array.from({ length: numGroups }, () => 0);
    const groups = Array.from({ length: numGroups }, () => []);

    for (let i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
        const currentItem = items[i];
        let minSizeIndex = 0;

        for (let j = 1; j < numGroups; j++) {
            if (groupSizes[j] < groupSizes[minSizeIndex]) {
                minSizeIndex = j;
            }
        }

        groups[minSizeIndex].push(currentItem);
        groupSizes[minSizeIndex] += currentItem.size;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numGroups; i++) {
        console.log(`Group ${i + 1} (total size ${groupSizes[i]}): ${groups[i].map(item => item.title).join(', ')}`);
    }
}

const items = [
    { title: 'Item A', size: 5 },
    { title: 'Item B', size: 1 },
    { title: 'Item C', size: 8 },
    { title: 'Item D', size: 2 },
    { title: 'Item E', size: 3 },
];

distributeItems(items, 3);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I've updated question with snippet. There is an answers to my question, unfortunately all of them is a solutions to most balanced groups which ignoring order of the items.

Comment: I don't have time to give a detailed answer, but this is solvable by an A* search. Your cost function is the sum of squares of differences of group size from the average. The nodes of your graph are, "Group `k` starts at `i`." Your heuristic is that the rest of the groups are all the same size. If you're clever about coding it, it can be very efficient.

Comment: Another variation is just to limit the size of the largest group. This can be done with a binary search on the size of the largest group, then seeing how many groups you got from a greedy match. This is faster and easier than A*, but doesn't give results that are as good for avoiding really small groups.

Comment: Thanks @btilly, you pointed into right direction, it does works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algo is the following:

1. Calculate total size of all items
2. Get size of a group
3. Iterate items and push to groups according to the current sum of item sizes

It doesn't include a case when there's both groups share equal amount of an item.

```js
const groupNum = 5;
const items=[{title:"Item A",size:5},{title:"Item B",size:18},{title:"Item C",size:10},{title:"Item D",size:12},{title:"Item E",size:4},{title:"Item F",size:3},{title:"Item G",size:1},{title:"Item H",size:2},{title:"Item I",size:9},{title:"Item J",size:9},{title:"Item K",size:11},{title:"Item L",size:2},{title:"Item M",size:4},{title:"Item N",size:16},{title:"Item O",size:38},{title:"Item P",size:11},{title:"Item R",size:2},{title:"Item S",size:8},{title:"Item T",size:4},{title:"Item U",size:3},{title:"Item V",size:14},{title:"Item W",size:3},{title:"Item X",size:7},{title:"Item Y",size:4},{title:"Item Z",size:3},{title:"Item 1",size:1},{title:"Item 2",size:10},{title:"Item 3",size:2},{title:"Item 4",size:5},{title:"Item 5",size:1},{title:"Item 6",size:2},{title:"Item 7",size:10},{title:"Item 8",size:1},{title:"Item 9",size:4},];

console.log(distributeItems(items, groupNum));

function distributeItems(items, groupNum) {
    const total = items.reduce((r, item) => r + item.size, 0);
    const chunkTotal = total / groupNum | 0;
    const groups = Array.from({ length: groupNum }, () => []);

    let sum = 0, groupIdx = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const group = groups[groupIdx];
        const item = items[i];
        sum += item.size;
        if (sum >= chunkTotal) {
            const right = chunkTotal - (sum - item.size);
            const left = sum = Math.min(chunkTotal, item.size - right);
            groupIdx++;
            // compare the right edge of the left chunk with the left edge of the right chunk (the next one)
            if (right < left && group.length) {
                groups[groupIdx].push(item);
            } else {
                group.push(item);
            }
            // just fill the last group
            if (groupIdx === groupNum - 1) {
                while (++i < items.length) groups[groupIdx].push(items[i]);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        group.push(item);

    }


    return groups;
}
```

And benchmarking against A* search suggested in the comments:

```
` Chrome/122
--------------------------------------------------
Alexander      1.00x | x100000 136 137 138 139 140
Mabel      35588.24x |     x10 484 488 493 499 519
--------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const groupNum = 5;
const items=[{title:"Item A",size:5},{title:"Item B",size:18},{title:"Item C",size:10},{title:"Item D",size:12},{title:"Item E",size:4},{title:"Item F",size:3},{title:"Item G",size:1},{title:"Item H",size:2},{title:"Item I",size:9},{title:"Item J",size:9},{title:"Item K",size:11},{title:"Item L",size:2},{title:"Item M",size:4},{title:"Item N",size:16},{title:"Item O",size:38},{title:"Item P",size:11},{title:"Item R",size:2},{title:"Item S",size:8},{title:"Item T",size:4},{title:"Item U",size:3},{title:"Item V",size:14},{title:"Item W",size:3},{title:"Item X",size:7},{title:"Item Y",size:4},{title:"Item Z",size:3},{title:"Item 1",size:1},{title:"Item 2",size:10},{title:"Item 3",size:2},{title:"Item 4",size:5},{title:"Item 5",size:1},{title:"Item 6",size:2},{title:"Item 7",size:10},{title:"Item 8",size:1},{title:"Item 9",size:4},];

function distributeItems(items, groupNum) {
    const total = items.reduce((r, item) => r + item.size, 0);
    const chunkTotal = total / groupNum | 0;
    const groups = Array.from({ length: groupNum }, () => []);

    let sum = 0, groupIdx = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const group = groups[groupIdx];
        const item = items[i];
        sum += item.size;
        if (sum >= chunkTotal) {
            const right = chunkTotal - (sum - item.size);
            const left = sum = Math.min(chunkTotal, item.size - right);
            groupIdx++;
            // compare the right edge of the left chunk with the left edge of the right chunk (the next one)
            if (right < left && group.length) {
                groups[groupIdx].push(item);
            } else {
                group.push(item);
            }
            // just fill the last group
            if (groupIdx === groupNum - 1) {
                while (++i < items.length) groups[groupIdx].push(items[i]);
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        group.push(item);

    }


    return groups;
}

// @benchmark Alexander
distributeItems(items, groupNum);

class Balancer {
    cost(groupSizes) {
        return groupSizes.reduce((cost, size) => cost + Math.pow(size - this.averageSize, 2), 0);
    }

    searchAStar(currentGroup, groupSizes, remainingItems) {
        if (currentGroup === this.groupNum) {
            return { cost: this.cost(groupSizes), groups: groupSizes };
        }

        let bestResult = { cost: Infinity, groups: null };

        for (let i = 1; i <= remainingItems.length; i++) {
            const newItem = remainingItems.slice(0, i);
            const newGroupSizes = groupSizes.slice();
            newGroupSizes[currentGroup] += newItem.reduce((total, item) => total + item.size, 0);

            const restResult = this.searchAStar(currentGroup + 1, newGroupSizes, remainingItems.slice(i));

            const totalResult = {
                cost: restResult.cost + this.cost(newGroupSizes),
                groups: [newItem].concat(restResult.groups),
            };

            if (totalResult.cost < bestResult.cost) {
                bestResult = totalResult;
            }
        }

        return bestResult;
    }

    distributeItems(items, groupNum) {
        this.items = items;
        this.groupNum = groupNum;
        this.averageSize = items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.size, 0) / groupNum;

        const result = this.searchAStar(0, Array(groupNum).fill(0), items);

        return result.groups.slice(0, groupNum);
    }
}

// @benchmark Mabel
new Balancer().distributeItems(items, groupNum);

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it provides results as expected. Still I've made a solution with A*.

Comment: @Mabel simplified the code a lot, should be much faster

Comment: @Mabel the code is so small there's no need in A* i believe

Comment: You are right, this one is indeed better and simpler.

Comment: @Mabel fixed the bug, and added a benchmark, check it out. Also your Balancer misses the last item. Also there could be slight difference in distribution but as I mentioned I didn't process equal edges of groups (where an item falls equal amount into 2 groups) smartly.

Answer (score 0):

I view this as a minimax problem: allocate items to bins in such a way that the maximum of the combined sizes for each bin is minimized. This will tend to reduce the variability of the amount allocated to each bin.

For example, if one item with size 3 were assigned to bin 1, 3 items with sizes 1, 4 and 2 were assigned to bin 2 and one item with size 6 were assigned to bin 3, the value would be:

```
[3, 1+4+2, 6].max #=> [3, 7, 6].max => 7
```

A better allocation would be:

```
[3+1, 4+2, 6].max #=> [4, 6, 6].max => 6
```

It is these maximum values we wish to minimize, hence the expression "minimax".

The code below is Ruby, but with explanations I will provide, it can be viewed as pseudo-code by those unfamiliar with Ruby.

I assume that each bin must include at least item. Note that a better solution could not be obtained by relaxing that constraint.

A minimax (optimal) solution can be obtain using dynamic programming. I will show the detailed calculations for an example, from which a recursive expression and associated code can be extrapolated.

---

Suppose there are 3 bins and 5 items with the sizes given below.

```
sizes = [3, 1, 4, 2, 6]
```

It is convenient to create the following hash.

```
h = { 1=>3, 2=>1, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>6 }
```

`h[3]`, for example, equals `sizes[3-1]`.

We now define the following empty hash `f`. (This section is optional reading.)

```
f = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
```

`f[b][n]` equals the mimimax solution if there are `b` bins and the first `n` elements of `sizes` to be allocated to the bins.

If `f` does have a key `k`, executing `f[k]` creates the hash `{k=>{}}`. Here are some examples.

```
f[3]         #=> {}
f            #=> {3=>{}} 
f[5][2] = 1  #=> 1
f            #=> {3=>{}, 5=>{2=>1}}
```

After reinitializing `f` consider bin 1.

---

**b = 1**

Items #1, #1 and #2 or #1, #2 and #3 could be allocated to bin 1. (Items #4 and #5 cannot be allocated to bin 1 because bins 2 and 3 each require at least one item.) The total sizes for each of these three combinations follows.

```
f[b][1] = h[1]                                              # 3
f[b][2] = f[b][1] + h[2]                                    # 4
f[b][3] = f[b][2] + h[3]                                    # 8
```

We now have:

```
f #=> {1=>{1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}}
```

This means, for example, that if the first `2` items were to be allocated to bin 1 the total sizes would be `f[1][2] #=> 4`. (`g = f[1] #=> {1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}`, `g[2] #=> 4`)

---

Now consider bin 2.

**b = 2**

Suppose only the first two items are to be allocated to the two bins. The only way that can be done is to allocate the first item to bin 1 and the second item to bin 2.

*n = 2*

```
f[b][n] = [h[n], f[b-1][n-1]].max                           # 3*
```

Now

```
f #=> {1=>{1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}, 2=>{2=>3}}
     ​
```

*n = 3*

If the first 3 items are allocated to the bins 1 and 2 that can be done in two ways:

- allocate #3 to bin 2 and #2 and #1 to bin 1; and
- allocate #3 and #2 to bin 2 and #1 to bin 1.

```
a1 = [h[n], f[b-1][n-1]].max                                # 4*
a2 = [h[n] + h[n-1], f[b-1][n-2]].max                       # 5
```

​
We select the smaller of the two:

```
f[b][n] = [a1, a2].min                                      # 4
```

We now have:

```
f #=> {1=>{1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}, 2=>{2=>3, 3=>4}}
```

`f[2][3] #=> 4`, for example, tells us that if the first 3 items are allocated to bins 1 and 2 the minimax (optimal) value (for the first 2 bins only) is 4 and from the calculations we see (and would make a note of it in code) that was achieved by allocating the item #3 to bin 2 and items #1 and #2 to bin 1.

*n = 4*

If the first 4 items must be allocated to the two bins that can be done in three ways:

- allocate #4 to bin 2 and #3, #2 and #1 to bin 1;
- allocate #4 and #3 to bin 2 and #2 and #1 to bin 1; and
- allocate #4, #3 and #2 to bin 2 and #1 bin 1.

```
a1 = [sizes[n], f[b-1][n-1]].max                            # 8
a2 = [sizes[n] + sizes[n-1], f[b-1][n-2]].max               # 6*
a3 = [sizes[n] + sizes[n-1] + sizes[n-2], f[b-1][n-3]].max  # 7
```

We select the smallest:

```
f[b][n] = [a1, a2, a3].min                                  # 6
```

This tells us that the mimimax value is 6 when the first 4 items are allocated to the first two bins. The calculations show this is achieved by allocating items #4 and #3 to bin 2 and #2 and #1 to bin 1.

We now have:

```
f #=> {1=>{1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}, 2=>{2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>6}}
```

We do not consider `n = 5` as bin 3 must contain at least one item.

We now add bin 3.

**b = 3**

For this bin we need only consider the allocation of all 5 items to the three bins.

*n = 5*

Between 1 and 3 items could be allocated to bin 3.

```
a1 = [sizes[n], f[b-1][n-1]].max                            #  6 *
a2 = [sizes[n] + sizes[n-1], f[b-1][n-2]].max               #  8
a3 = [sizes[n] + sizes[n-1] + sizes[n-2], f[b-1][n-3]].max  # 12
```

```
f[b][n] = [a1, a2, a3].min                                  #  6
```

```
f #=> {1=>{1=>3, 2=>4, 3=>8}, 2=>{2=>3, 3=>4, 4=>6}, 3=>{5=>6}}
```

We now know the value of the minimax (optimal) solution is 6.

---

It remains to construct the optimal allocation. For bin 3 we see that only item five is assigned to bin 3. That leaves 4 items so we inspect `f[2][4]`, where we see that it is optimal to assign 2 items to bin 2, leaving 4-2 = 2 to be assigned to bin 1. In summary,

- Bin 1: items #1 and #2, with total size 4 (3+1);
- Bin 2: items #3 and #4, with total size 6 (4+2); and
- Bin 3: item #5, with size 6

We can confirm that the optimal allocation has the correct minimax value:

```
[4, 6, 6].max #=> 6
```